# Can I have a aws windows instance with GUI (not remote desktop connection...)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to open browser in the aws instance (from server side) and take a screenshot. In my case if any rdp client connected, I am able to take a screenshot, but when no one rdp is connected, taken screenshot is black scree.
My thoughts are: it seems aws instance uses my desktop gui (monitor).
Please help me with your experience and advise.
Thanks,

Comment: How are you taking the screenshot when nobody is connected?

Answer (score 0):

actually that does make sense.for screenshot the gui needs to be loaded somewhere... 
. for this you can create a  jumpbox in aws (another instance) .. use that jumpbox to do rdp and the screenshot .. 
so in that scenario your desktop gui will not be used..